# AD User stuck in a service

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

So I am stuck with a really off issue. THe issue occurs when I changed my domain user password. SInce I am a domain admin also, and the user is being used with many services during the last password period.
The problem is that few machines are trying to login with my domain ID in background making my ID locked out every 3 minute. I am able to trace computernames with manageengine AD Audit, but I cant trace out what service is trying to login.

I have clearead Windows credential from 2 out of 5 machines, but they still have same behavious. No service in services.msc have my password.

I am open for console commands, since they have more power in lesser clicks.

How can I trace what service is using my credentials?
Domain: Server 2012 R2
Antivirus: Kaspersky (installed during last 30 days)

Comment: You can query DC logs to find where your account is being used to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you can find the machines then you should be able to look at the services on those machines to find the service that is using your credentials.
2. Please stop doing this. Your user account should be a standard user account and you should have a separate user account that you use specifically for domain administration. Stop using your user account as a service account. Use an account that you create specifically for these services or use a Managed Service Account.

Comment: Thanks Joeqwerty. I dont usually use my personal account as service account but I made a mistake this time. I have detected 4 Clients and 2 servers that are sending my account credentials to AD. I have not installed any software on these machines using my accuont but just joined them to my domain. Next day i changed the password and BANGG. :(

Comment: Also, for the clients, I tried to look in services.msc, but there are no services associated with my name. All goes with LocalService, NetworkService, LocalSystem etc. Can you help finding in any such machine?

Comment: You should also try reviewing scheduled tasks for jobs that may include those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, create yourself a new domain admin account.  That way, you're not constantly getting locked out while you're trying to work.

Then, for each machine that you know is generating the logon attempts:

- Check that you didn't just leave your old account logged in.  If you did, log it out and see if the problem goes away on that machine.
- Reboot the machine, see if the problem goes away on that machine.
- If it is still happening, log in with your *new* account, and use Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to look for any processes running in the context of your old account.
- The next steps depend on what (if any) processes you find.  Play it by ear, or update the question with the new information.

Comment: Hi Harry, apologies for a long delay as I was travelling. I tried ADAudit+ to track out the systems. However, i couldnt track which process are using my account. I will use Process Monitor now.